# How to let user know that they won't be charged until the last step?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

Let's say I have a booking app (for a room) and before being charged, the user needs to go through a couple of steps to confirm their details. Only at the last step will they be asked to "Pay Now".

AirBnB just uses "Next" with the Total Price is indicated in every page. This text changes to "Confirm Booking" at the last step.

Is this enough to tell the user that they can safely go through all the details first without being charged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common technique (I don't know whether AirBnB does this) is to have step-by-step summary bar (there's probably a recognised name for this...) along the top of the page clearly showing that "Payment" will be the last step. For instance:

[image]

clearly shows that there are four stages to the "Checkout" process, but payment will only be taken at the end.

---

<sup>Credit: image taken from https://www.careshop.co.uk/order to which I have no affiliation.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

AirBnB's experience is a great benchmark for this function. I suggest you copy the same.

Since yours is a booking app, it is clear to the user that they have to pay to fulfil their use case. In that case, the user also wants to know as much as possible before they pay, and would not be averse to interact if it generates information which can give both the app and the user value-add. Suggesting a total price at every step (and reflecting any changes in real time that may arise with added new information) and then doing a checkout in the end is a beautiful way to solve this problem.